# Why is it bad to use goto?

Tags: language-agnostic, goto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

I just came across some C# code that had a goto statement in it (which I didn't even know C# supported).  I only vaguely remember hearing about goto statements in one of my college classes.  I seem to remember my professor saying it should never be used but I don't remember why.

Should I consider rewriting this piece of code or is this unlikely to cause problems?