# What is wrong with using goto?

Tags: c++, goto

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why is it bad to use goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444060/why-is-it-bad-to-use-goto)
>   [GOTO still considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

I was ramdomming through xkcd and saw this one (if also read some negative texts about them some years ago):
[image: your slow connection sucks, get a faster one to see this image]
What is actually wrong with it? Why are goto's even possible in C++ then?

Why should I **not** use them?

Comment: This blog on the topic is worth a read: http://blog.smartbear.com/development/goto-still-has-a-place-in-modern-programming-no-really/

Comment: The best reason to avoid GOTO is exemplified by the xkcd cartoon: if you use GOTO, you're likely to be attacked by a dinosaur.

Comment: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46789/465053) with same graphic on another post.

Comment: Check out Dijkstra's original [Go to statement considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html). But don't forget Knuth's [Structured programming with goto statements](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/356635.356640) which explains why you might use them and how they can fit with rather than oppose the goals of structured programming

Comment: It is wrong to use GOTO, if one can achieve the same thing with an IF...ELSE... statement, a FOR or a DO ... WHILE loop, an automatically destructed RAII object or any other high level construct. There are cases, though, where a single well placed GOTO eliminates duplicate code and/or a temporary boolean, without making the code unclear or ureadable. And in those cases, it SHOULD be used.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Because they lead to [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

In the past, programming languages didn't have while loops, if statements, etc., and programmers used goto to make up the logic of their programs. It lead to an unmaintainable mess.

That's why the CS gods created methods, conditionals and loops. [Structured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming) programming was a revolution at the time.

gotos are appropriate in a few places, such as for jumping out of nested loops.

Comment: Jumping out of nested loops are the *only* instance I have used goto statements. Even then, I refactor my code to simply return early when possible.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging that `goto` still has a purpose on rare occasions.

Comment: I remember reading gotos are often used by some tools that auto-generate code, like parser generators etc.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I thought I'd add one more use for goto. In SQR goto is commonly used as a 'continue' in a loop. Many database languages don't have continues in the language so they put a goto at the end of the loop and call it if they need to 'continue'.

Comment: More accurate to say because they *can* easily lead to spaghetti code if not used wisely. Sometimes it is actually the cleanest, DRYest way of doing things, especially in languages that don't focus on structured programming, as I've just discovered when trying to make a loop continue in T-SQL.

Comment: A `return` can be used instead of  `goto` to jump out of nested loops. For example, extract the nested loops into a new function and return from there when the condition that triggers the `goto` is satisfied. I only see `goto` being used only to get an extra bit of performance

Comment: "In the past, programming languages didn't have .... if statements"  err.  Basic always had if statements... as did most assembly languages.  (although "if" might be "jump if zero")  As for using goto in nested loops; personally I'd argue that if you want to jump out a nested loop; then you make a function and return from it.

Comment: @mljrg That create a new function thing often isn't a good solution when your current function has a bunch of context with it that you'd have to pass around. Also, what if you have nested loops and conditions and you don't want to jump all the way out? Once you go beyond basic code this sort of scenario definitely happens here and there and goto is a very clean, easy, readable solution.

Comment: @Andrew The important thing is that at the end the code should be as much understandable as possible, whether using a `goto` or not. The best solution will depend on a case basis, but I still have to see a `goto` proving to be the best understandable solution. Perhaps this is because I mostly use only functional programming.

Comment: @Andrew Beware that a function with a bunch of context is perhaps doing to much, and a candidate to be broken into simpler functions, thus making the final code more understandable. Again, I suppose there will be exceptional cases ... but very frequently in C programs I see enormous functions that can scare anyone a lot. I wonder how many bugs are hidden there  ;-)

Comment: @mljrg I gave you the instances in which `goto` is the best solution: nested loops and conditions. Try looping through multiple dimensions, or looping through a bunch of trees or linked lists simultaneously. Video game and graphing applications come to mind, where you have lots of structured data loading, graphics, stitching data together and apart, etc. In some situations, where you are exactly in an algorithm's "steps" can be several pieces of context in and of itself. Splitting your code up into many small functions is a bad idea, because then you're looping over many call stack operations.

Comment: @Andrew A good compiler would let it be instructed to inline the function calls as appropriate to avoid a negative performance impact inside nested loops, while retaining the greater understandability of having smaller focused functions. If you are in C++ you can throw an exception to do a non-local return from deep inside several nested function calls, and likewise,
it can be done in C using `setjmp` and `longjmp` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685406/practical-usage-of-setjmp-and-longjmp-in-c)). But for a typical few cases I admit that a `goto` may be the best option.

Comment: @mljrg That's true until you factor in the context you have to pass around and return in order to replace the `goto` functionality, and then it's not going to get optimized. Both of your other examples are slow, and exceptions are not made for this purpose.

Comment: JavaScript lets you `break` out of labelled loops, which I've found useful.

Comment: In many cases "spaghetti code" is result after desperate attempts to avoid use of `goto`! And BTW too many examples in MSDN (Win32 API) include `goto`. In Linux source you can find `goto` as well!

Answer (score 111):

Nothing is wrong with `goto` if it is used properly.  The reason it is "taboo" is because in the early days of C, programmers (often coming from an assembly background) would use `goto` to create incredibly hard-to-understand code.

Most of the time, you can live without `goto` and be fine.  There are a few instances, however, where `goto` can be useful.  The prime example is a case like:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
            ...
            if (condition)
                goto break_out;
            ....
        }
    }
}
break_out:
```

Using a `goto` to jump out of a deeply-nested loop can often be cleaner than using a condition variable and checking it on every level.

Using `goto` to implement subroutines is the main way it is abused.  This creates so-called "spaghetti code" that is unnecessarily difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: What if there are some automatic objects constructed on the stack, which are local inside the loop? Goto will jump to some other place, jumping over the end of the blocks, where the destructors for these objects are called. Right? In most cases, it won't do anything bad. But there are cases where it WILL do, including losing user's data etc.

Comment: @SasQ: The compiler is responsible for ensuring that the actual "jmp" instruction generated for the `goto` is preceded by whatever code would be necessary to get rid of inner scope variables.

Comment: It's not true that `goto` can jump between functions. C has `longjmp()` for that, and C++ has exceptions.

Comment: regarding your claim that "goto can also be used to jump from one function into another without making a function call": [**your claim that you can use `goto` to "jump from one function into another without making a function call" is wrong as explained by here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17357266/52074) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17357238/52074) and also see the comment directly above by @celticminstrel.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith- You're right, I must have been thinking about `longjmp` (same problematic concept, different interface). Fixed.

Comment: If you need a `O(N^3)` loop, maybe `goto` is the least of your concerns.

Comment: @anastaciu If you don't ever work with such loops, maybe `goto` is the least of *your* concerns.

Comment: @Andrew I try as much as I can, not to, and it's not so hard, I'm very doubtful that any company nowadays accepts a piece of code with over O(N^2), and even O(N^2) is a stretch.

Comment: @anastaciu Plenty of companies would. There is a vast variety of different software out there, and many of them require complicated nesting.

Comment: The reason it is taboo predates C by several years. Dijkstra’s letter was published in 1968.

Answer (score 49):

There is nothing wrong with `goto` in itself.  It's a very useful construct in programming and has many valid uses. The best that comes to mind is structured resource freeing in C programs.

Where `goto` goes wrong is when it is abused.  Abuse of `goto` can lead to thoroughly unreadable and unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 35):

In 1968, [Edsger Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Dijkstra) wrote a famous letter to the editor of *Communications of the ACM* [GOTO is considered harmful](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF) in which he laid out the case for structured programming with **while loops** and **if...then...else** conditionals. When GOTO is used to substitute for these control structures, the result is very often [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). Pretty much every programming language in use to day is a structured programming language, and use of GOTOs has been pretty much eliminated. In fact, Java, Scala, Ruby, and Python don't have a `goto` command at all.

C, C++ and Perl still do have a GOTO command, and there are situations (in C particularly) where a [GOTO is useful](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/goto.html), for example a break statement that exits multiple loops, or as a way of concentrating cleanup code in a single place in a function even when there are multiple ways to terminate the function (e.g. by returning error codes at multiple points in the progress of a function). But generally its use should be restricted to specific design patterns that call for it in a controlled and recognized way.

(In C++, it's better to use RAII or a [ScopeGuard](http://www.zete.org/people/jlehrer/scopeguard.html) [(more)](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Idioms.ScopeGuardPointer) instead of using GOTO for cleanup. But GOTO is a [frequently used idiom in the Linux kernel](http://web.archive.org/web/20100211132600/http://kerneltrap.org/node/553/2131) ([another source](https://lkml.org/lkml/2003/1/12/128)) which is a great example of idiomatic C code.)

The XKCD comic is a joke on the question "Should GOTO always be considered harmful when there are certain specific design patterns that are helped greatly by its use?"

Comment: And that GOTO's went out with the (computing) dinosaurs

Comment: @Gerry: that's a good one. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Actually, with the `goto` he used (to `goto` a subroutine of some sort), raptors should attack him.

Comment: I find that the DIjkstra explanation (and its direct consequences) is the true reason not to use goto, and not just the "unstructured code" everybody think it´s all about. There are more implications, and you are right to mention it.

Comment: Java don't have a `goto` command but a `break` who serve the same purpose

Comment: You guys should have used C64 Basic V2.0. released more than 10 years after the Dijkstra's paper, this language has neither **else** *nor* the loops, besides a `for` loop that you could misnest by accident. Bill Gates is personally responsible for this abomination, BTW.

Comment: "Java don't have a goto command but a break who serve the same purpose" No. break is much more limited in scope. Break can only be used to exit the loop prematurely and to exit switch block, which seems to be like a C carryover.

Answer (score 11):

Did you google the issue?

The founder of the anti-goto movement is Edsger Dijskstra with his legendary "Goto Considered Harmful"

To get you started you can goto (ha ha!) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOTO

Comment: Ironically, he actually tolerated far more GOTO than programmers today. For Djikstra, forward GOTO is okay, backward GOTO and GOTO into the inside of the loop is not.

Answer (score 10):

It's possible in C++ because it's possible in C. Whether you should or shouldn't use it is long-standing religious war.

It was a design goal of C++ that 99-point-something percent of C programs in the wild should compile and run with the same functionality in C++. Including `goto` was part of the effort to reach that goal.

Comment: Apparently the author of the question is unaware why "goto" is available in C, too.

Comment: C++ is **not** a superset of C.

Comment: It's not, but one of the original goals (and, apparently, banes) of C++ was strong compatibility with C. And I still don't get what you are so upset about.

Comment: @kon to be fair you have to write really ancient style C code to make it not valid in C++, mod russians back up :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks, I didn't know there was russian mob around here :)

Comment: I haven’t ever heard anyone argue that you should ever use `goto` in new C++ programs. Fortunately.

Comment: @Ole You should definitely use `goto` at times in new c++ code.

Comment: @Anycorn There are some handy (and quite commonly used) features in C that are unfortunately not available in C++ (e.g. automatic void* casts and designated initializers)