# Can llvm emit code that jumps to a given address within a function?

Tags: c++, c, llvm

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357199/using-goto-function-across-different-functions) question, is it possible for llvm to generate code that may jump to an arbitrary address within a function in the same address space?
i.e.

```
      void func1() {
       ...
       <code that jumps to addr2>
       ...
       }

       void func2() {
       ...
addr2:
       <some code in func2()>
       ...
       }
```

Comment: This is considered bad practice, because it may cause "spaghetti code" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). Write instead a new function func3, that you invoke from func1 and func2

Comment: @Brainless: "Spaghetti code" is a risk to maintainability. Since generated code doesn't need to be maintained (instead, you maintain the source from which it was generated), it doesn't matter how spaghettified it is.

Comment: @MSalters The question is more about the possibility of emitting such code, not actually writing it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,No,Yes,No,(yes) - It depends on the level you look at and what you mean with `possible`:

- Yes, as the llvm backend will produce target specific assembler
  instructions and those assembler instructions allow to set the
  program counter to an abitrary value.
- No, because - as far as I know - the llvm ir (the intermediate representation into which a frontend like clang compiles your c code) hasn't any instructions that would allow abitrary jumps between (llvm-ir) functions.
- Yes, because the frontend COULD certainly produce code, that simulates that behaviour (breaking up func2 into multiple separate functions).
- No, because C and C++ don't allow such jumps to ARBITRARY positions and so clang will not compile any program that tries to do that (e.g. via `goto`)
- (yes) the c `longjmp` macro jumps back to a place in the control flow that you have already visited (where you called `setjmp`) but also restores (most) of the system state. **EDIT:** However, this is UB if func2 isn't somewhere up in the current callstack from where you jump.