# Why are goto, break, continue and multiple return statements considered bad practice

Tags: c, coding-style

I've recently been taking a C course as part of a university degree. We have been forbidden from using `goto`, `break` and `continue`, and must only use a single `return` statement from a function.

I have been writing C for many years as a hobby without these restrictions and have been struggling to write in the style they require - often ending up with mountains of nested `if` statements. I try to avoid `goto` where possible, but have a habit of using `break`, `continue` and multiple `return` statements very liberally and have never had any issues.

Why are these features considered bad practice?

Comment: Never heard about this strange "requirement". Best thing you can do is to ask your instructor or lecturer.

Comment: Did you try looking for answers on [softwareengineering.se]?

Comment: That seems like a contradictory set of requirements.  Following a single-entry, single-exit (SESE) pattern typically explicitly *recommends* using `goto`.  In C, single-exit often can be a good idea since C lacks RAII, and having multiple exit points makes it more likely that a function will fail to properly free resources on all of them. `goto`, *when used properly*, is great for managing resources without an indentation pyramid of doom.

Comment: user2248702, "Why are these features considered bad practice?" --> not always bad practice.  Code for clarity. Use `break, continue, goto` when needed.  avoid them, but use them when it is the best choice - which is usually rarely.

Comment: Don't they have opinions about _"mountains of nested `if` statements"_ too? That's usually avoidable by making short functions which does "one thing" only.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, and then what about mountains of tiny functions which are never re-used when you could have the logic cleanly in 1 single 100-line function! I break out code into multiple functions for 1) reuse, and 2) readability. A single well-written 200 line function is more-readable than a dozen functions all calling each other once, without real re-use nor need to be multiple functions. It's all tradeoffs.

Comment: @jamesdlin, exactly! I stated that too, in my answer: `goto` is best used to create functions with a single `return` statement to exit. So, no `goto` _and_ a single `return` is a bit of a contradictory requirement.

Comment: Matter of opinion.

Comment: @GabrielStaples The good thing with short functions that does one thing _is_ readability and to limit the amount of nested `if`s. It simplifies testing too. I don't consider reuse a requirement for putting sections of code in functions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yeah, I have seen code both ways. It's a matter of taste, for sure. I _hate_ `auto` in C++, for instance, because it makes the code so _unreadable_. Others _love_ `auto`, because it makes the code so _readable_. Wait, that's opposite! How can it be both? Different brains I guess.

Comment: @GabrielStaples :-) I love `auto` for iterators and generally when writing generic code. I don't love it as much when reading complex code where it's not obvious what type `auto` really is. :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I've had tons of issues there too! The type of the iterator in an `unordered_map`, for instance, is a `std::pair<keyType, valueType>`, giving it the `.first` and `.second` member variables. Not obvious to anyone new to `unordered_map`s. So, I personally updated the examples in the cppreference reference wiki for it here to show that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is highly subjective, as all 4 of those things have trade-offs--pros and cons.

Ask your teacher, and report back here.

`goto` has an unnecessarily bad reputation. People fear it *waaay* more than they should! I think it is because using `goto` can be easily abused, especially if you jump outside your function, or jump backwards (upwards in the code). If you jump only downwards, however, and within the same function, *not* crossing over variable declarations in the process, `goto` can be an *excellent* technique to help you achieve a clean single `return` statement at the end of a function. In C, it can be the *perfect* way to handle errors in complex initializations! See my usage in my answer here: [Opaque C structs: various ways to declare them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488289/4561887). See also the **Additional reading and justification for valid usage of goto in error handling for professional code** section at the bottom of my answer there.

In some organizations, including some *safety-critical* embedded microcontroller applications I have worked in in the self-driving car industry, using `goto` can even be *required*. I've worked in code bases where the above error handling technique with a single `return` and using `goto` was *required* by my organization's coding guidelines. It's *not* automatically evil. Rather, it's a tradeoff with pros and cons. Unfortunately, many people I've worked with also have an unfounded revulsion towards `goto` which was probably planted by their teacher, like your teacher for instance. This revulsion can lead to some pretty awful code at times when `goto` would have beautified and simplified it *tremendously*.

Note also that in C++ there are other ways to do error handling that aren't as accessible in C, but still, `goto` could be used.

`break` and `continue` are much less-easily abused. Perhaps the only real argument against them is code clarity.

Ex: do something 10 times:

```c
// fine, but perhaps not as clear
const int NUM_TIMES = 10;
int i = 0;
while (true)
{
    printf("i = %i\n", i);

    i++;
    if (i >= NUM_TIMES)
    {
        break;
    }
}

// clearer (withOUT `break`)
int i = 0;
while (i < NUM_TIMES)
{
    printf("i = %i\n", i);
    i++
}

// or
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TIMES; i++)
{
    printf("i = %i\n", i);
}

// The above example is trivial, but imagine you are NOT just 
// incrementing a number! The non-`break` while loop with your
// condition up-front can be clearer. The `break` option is just
// fine too, but it's a matter of taste.
```

A single `return` statement is best achieved when using `goto`. Otherwise, it requires tons of nesting. So, that is contrary to your teacher's guidance, it seems.

Many people, however, opt for multiple `return` statements to exit a function early and avoid tons of nested braces. It's basically a tradeoff of:

1. tons of nesting, OR
2. `goto`, and a single `return`, OR
3. multiple `return`s

In languages like C, I use `goto` and a single `return`, unless my stinking peers won't approve it, and they fight with me, in which case I conform to whoever is reviewing me so I can get my stinking code merged. :) (Replace "stinking" with "beloved", for your peers, of course).

In languages like C++, where developers hate `goto` even more than in C, I generally use multiple returns or extra nesting and breaking the code out into sub-functions--again, to appease my peers who don't know and love C.

In Python, where `goto` does not exist, I use multiple returns.

At the end of the day, ask your teacher. Take mental notes. *Learn* why they are doing it. Learn from us. Learn from books. Form your own opinions. Begin recognizing trends and "best practices", and form your own opinions. If you need to do what your teacher wants, even if they're wrong, for the grade, do it. But do it the "better" way you determine outside that class.

In code reviews, if your stinking peer won't approve your beautiful `goto` usage, try to convince them. If you can't, make the change to avoid `goto`, reduce friction, and move on. It's not worth fighting about. *Everything* is a tradeoff. There are many "right" ways to do things.

Note to all: I say "stinking" in jest. I am very grateful for the job that I have.

#### TODO (*Notes to self*):

Try forcing `goto` to jump outside the function, even if it produces undefined behavior, as a demo to prove it is dumb:

1. [goto jump outside function](https://www.google.com/search?q=goto+jump+outside+function&oq=goto+jump+outside+function&aqs=chrome..69i57.2997j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44843514/4561887

Comment: _"especially if you jump outside your function"_ - How is that even possible with `goto`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I haven't actually tried it, but I'm pretty sure if you disable enough warnings and errors in your compiler flags, you can make `goto` jump *anywhere* in the code. Maybe was more common in the very early days of programming with older compilers? Compilers don't have to produce _runnable_ or _correct_ executables. They just have to produce executables.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I may come back to this and try that sometime, but it's not high priority right now. If I do, I'll add it to my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo.

Answer (score 0):

With (purely) structured programming you can look at the structured statements to get a feel for the flow of the logic in your function. The flow is clearly visible since the contained statements are indented. Also, when you see a statement like

```
while (someCondition) {
   ...
}
/*Is someCondition false here?*/
```

you know that the contained statement sequence will be executed zero or more times until *someCondition* is false. However, with goto and goto-like statements (break, continue and early return) you throw this out of the window. You now have too look really carefully at every line for jumps buried in the code. Statements like the one above can **potentially be lying**; if there is a break in the middle of the while statement, *someCondition* may be true after the while statement has been executed. Ouch! With early returns you also cannot have post-conditions at the end of a functions, i.e. conditions that must hold true for the result or before the function returns. So to summarize: The virtue of structured programming is that it makes programs easier to reason about.

Comment: *The virtue of structured programming is that it makes programs easier to reason about.*  Except when it doesn't.  **Forcing** an algorithm into some predefined straitjacket implementation makes programs **harder** to reason about.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Only when this "forcing" is done in a substandard way.

Comment: Force-fitting an algorithm into some unnatural flow just to fit some preconceived, close-minded way to write code **is** substandard.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Please point me to such an algorithm that does not lend itself to pure structured programming.

Comment: How about you prove such an algorithm doesn't exist, since you're providing this as an answer?