# Weird behaiviour of scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

```
if (a % 5) {
    goto ask;
}
else {
    goto main;
}

ask:
printf("Do You Want To Exit ? Y \\ N . . . \n");
scanf("%c", &YN);
getch();
if (YN == 'Y') {
y:
    system("cls");
    YN = 1;
    goto sign;
}
else if (YN == 'y') {
    goto y;
}
else if (YN == 'N') {
n:
    system("cls");
    YN = 0;
    goto sign;
}
else if (YN == 'n') {
    goto n;
}
else {
    printf("Sorry ..Didn't Catch that ... ");
    goto ask;
}
```

Can someone help me understand what is wrong?
For some reason the output I get from this code is
"Do u want to exit y\n ?"
getchar ...
"sorry didnt catch that do u want to exit y\n ? "

It looks like it jumped over the `scanf()` for the first time and the program went directly to the `else` ==> `"sorry i didnt get that"`
and only in the second time it fiugres out how to use the `scanf()`.

Comment: Assembler might be more suitable for you given your style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf()` reads characters with `%c` and yes, the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press [after your previous input] is pretty much vaild for `%c` [Check the below spoiler].

> ENTER key press == newline

use

```
scanf(" %c", &YN);  //mind the space brefore `%c`
       ^
       |
```

to ignore any previously-stored [also, leading] whitespace [including a newline.]

<sup>Note: This also eliminates the need for your `getch();`</sup>

Comment: ....and to dear @downvoter, may I know the reson, and if possible , some suggestions to improve my answer?

Comment: Thats actually helped but i didnt understand why is the"
 " helped ...?

Comment: and one more thing if were at it .. the program asks me  about the exit every time instead of every 5 times .. something wrong with my a % 5 at the beggining ?

Comment: what `""` helped? i did not get you.

Comment: @unix14 i don't know what is `a` and how it's been handled, but logically, i think it should be `if (!(a%5))`, as per your requirement.

Comment: ok everybody i just finished all the bugs :) thank you very much fellas !!

how can i put 2 statements in else if btw ?

Comment: @unix14 again, what is `put 2 statements in else if`? you're already doing that in case of `Y` and `N`, aren't you?

Answer (score 2):

When `scanf` reads anything, it leaves the newline added by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the input buffer. The `"%c"` format reads any character in the input buffer, including newlines. So the first call will read and extract one character from the input buffer, but the next call will read the newline character left over from the previous call.

Adding a leading space to the format string tells `scanf` to read (and ignore) any whitespace (space, tab, newlines) before it tries to parse and extract your format.

I recommend you read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Add a space before `%c` to skip the newline character from the `stdin` which you had pressed after entering data for the `scanf` for the first time. This happens because `scanf` does not consume the `\n` character(Enter key) which you press after you enter any character .As the Enter key(`\n`) is also a character,it gets consumed by the `scanf` the second time and hence does not wait for further input.

Also,using `goto`s is usually bad practice. See [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto) for more info about this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `getch()` you are basically doing the same thing twice.