# does goto statement impact performance in c#

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, coding-style, goto

Is there performance impact of `GOTO` statement in `c#` code, instead of using `loop` or multiple separate user defined `functions`.

I am not sure but memory jump may occur with `GOTO` statement and can impact performance.

Comment: Performance impact or not, it will literally ruin your maintainability. Never use `GOTO`s, unless you're stuck in a really specific niche problem without any alternatives.

Comment: What performance difference did you find when you tried using `goto`? You did try it, right? I'm not as convinced as Pierre-Luc that simply using a `goto` means ruining your maintainability. And of course, it's a mandatory way to write fall-through `case` blocks. On the other hand, for flow control a `goto` does leave a lot to be desired, and pretty much always can be avoided. So you might as well; even if maintainability isn't ruined by a `goto`, it definitely gets a bit tarnished. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Methods are made to enhance readability. Classic `for` and `while` loops are easily distinguishable and easy to read. `GOTO`s can only make a huge mess, going all the way against basic OOP principles, SRP and will skyrocket your cyclomatic complexity through the roof while preventing any testability. I dare you to try to understand a 5k lines method with gotos in exactly the same time than a clean and structured OOP architecture. And honestly if you're trying to micro-optimize stuff like loops and methods (surely for absolutely no gain), just move to assembly already.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: who said anything about a method with five thousand lines? Give me a break...just because `goto` statements can be part of code that is otherwise also awful, that's no reason to believe that one `goto` statement in your code is literally going to ruin that code.

Comment: @Peter He talked about using GOTOs instead of methods. If the program makes 5k lines, that means you have a 5k lines single method. And we're not talking about one goto here (even if it's dangerous enough already), but replacing all the loops with em.

Comment: @Pieree-LucPineault: you are right i have legacy code with 6K lines having multiple `goto` statements i am avoiding as much as possible with `loops` but some are unavoidable.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: I'm amazed that you feel it's reasonable to infer all that from the question as posted, considering no such specifics at all are included. In any case, your statement to which I was referring (barely as an aside at that) was far more broad than that, implying that _any_ use of even a single `goto` would be disastrous. An idea that clearly is just not true.

Comment: One rare place where GOTOs are the clearest expression is to implement state transitions.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't.

It's hard to answer "does it impact peformance" without knowing what the alternative is but I'll make up a sample:

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        var x = 7;
        switch(x) // START SWITCH
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("World");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Uh...");
                break;
        }
        // END SWITCH
        // START GOTO
        if (x == 1)
        {
            goto Hello;
        }
        else if (x == 2)
        {
            goto World;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Uh...");
        goto End;
    Hello:
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        goto End;
    World:
        Console.WriteLine("World");
    End:
        // END GOTO
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Compiling this with C# in release mode (using sharplab.io default 2.9.0) yields the following IL (i.e. bytecode for you Java folk):

```
.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit C
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void M () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 99 (0x63)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] int32
        )

        IL_0000: ldc.i4.7
        IL_0001: stloc.0
        // START SWITCH
        IL_0002: ldloc.0
        IL_0003: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0004: beq.s IL_000c

        IL_0006: ldloc.0
        IL_0007: ldc.i4.2
        IL_0008: beq.s IL_0018

        IL_000a: br.s IL_0024

        IL_000c: ldstr "Hello"
        IL_0011: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0016: br.s IL_002e

        IL_0018: ldstr "World"
        IL_001d: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0022: br.s IL_002e

        IL_0024: ldstr "Uh..."
        IL_0029: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        // END SWITCH
        // START GOTO
        IL_002e: ldloc.0
        IL_002f: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0030: beq.s IL_0042

        IL_0032: ldloc.0
        IL_0033: ldc.i4.2
        IL_0034: beq.s IL_004e

        IL_0036: ldstr "Uh..."
        IL_003b: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0040: br.s IL_0058

        IL_0042: ldstr "Hello"
        IL_0047: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_004c: br.s IL_0058

        IL_004e: ldstr "World"
        IL_0053: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        // END GOTO
        IL_0058: ldstr "Done"
        IL_005d: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0062: ret
    } // end of method C::M

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20bf
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method C::.ctor

} // end of class C
```

The switch form has 3 `beq` and 1 `br.s` and the goto form has 2 `beq` and 2 `br.s`, other than that they are identical.  The cost of `br.s` is presumably less than or equal to the cost of `beq` so the cost of the goto approach is not greater than the cost of the switch approach.

Finally, using goto is a bad idea.  If you want to argue about that fact please do so on a different question like this one: [What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)