# C++ Birthday Probability

Tags: c++

I am trying to teach myself C++ in preparation for graduate school this coming fall but I am having some trouble with this birthday paradox problem. My code seems to run ok but I am not getting the correct output. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

```
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ctime>

 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int trials = 100000;
    int birthdays[50];
    int numMatches;


    for(int i = 2; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        numMatches = 0;

        for(int j = 1; j <= trials; j++)
        {

            for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                birthdays[k] = (rand() % 365) + 1;
            }

            int m = 1;
            bool matched = false;
            while(m < i && !matched){
                int n = m + 1;

            while(n <= i && !matched){
                if(birthdays[m] == birthdays[n]){
                    numMatches++;
                    matched = true;
                }
                n++;
            }
                m++;
            }
        }

        cout << "Probability of " << i << " people in a room sharing a birthday is \t"
          << ( float(numMatches) / float(trials) ) << endl;
    }  
}
```

Comment: nice comment, solves the problem completely...

Comment: What output were you expecting and what output are you getting?

Comment: well for the 24th person it should be close to .50 but I am getting like 0.001234

Comment: What @MitchWheat is trying to say is that doing a static analysis of your program flow is a skill you can learn that will help you with programming.  It might not have been put politely, but that may reflect the lack of evidence that you have attempted to debug your code before posting as a question.

Comment: @paddy: couldn't have put it better. :) and Morgan your statement "...well for the 24th person it should be close to .50 ...
" is incorrect. This probability surpasses 1/2   for n = 23 (with value about 50.7%)

Comment: As a hint, your loop starting with `for (m=1; ...` does literally nothing but set `m` to `1`.

Comment: I do debugg my programs but I am still not understanding the problem with my output thanks for the advice though

Comment: You only are using the value 1 for m.

Comment: fixed the error there with m

Comment: No you didn't ;)  `for(m = 1; k <= i; m++)` still never enters the loop.  Anyway, I don't understand why you generate all these values in the loop, and then only use the last one from each loop as a match.

Comment: ok, fixed it now lol

Comment: I think your aim is to test if 2 people in room of 2-50 people share birthday, not if 2-50 people share birthday as you say in output. And that's 2 people out of **23** have 50.7%, not 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not computing the probability of two people in a room of 50 sharing a birthday. There's several bugs, mostly with indexing, but here's the biggest issue:

```
for(int j = 1; j <= trials; j++) {
    // assigns a random birthday to the first i people (should be 0 indexed)
    for(k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        birthdays[k] = (rand() % 365) + 1;
    // Does *exactly* the same thing as the previous loop, overwriting what
    // the initial loop did. Useless code
    for(m = 1; m <= i; m++)
        birthdays[m] = (rand() % 365) + 1;
    // At this point, m = k = i + 1. Here you check if
    // the i + 1st array value has the same b-day. It will, because they're
    // the same thing. Note you never set the i + 1st value so the loops
    // above did nothing
    if(birthdays[k] == birthdays[m])
        ++numMatches;
}
```

So what you've got here is something like:

- Perform 48 iterations of the following (from your first loop which goes from 2 to 50: no idea where those values came from)

  - For each of those 48 iterations, perform 10k iterations of:

    - assign a bunch of random stuff to an array overwriting stuff
    - Ignore the values you wrote in the array, do a comparison that's always true and increment numMatches by 1

Answer (score 0):

I think the code must be something like this.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int birthdays[10000][50];
  int numMatches;
  int trials=10000,check;
  for(int n=0;n<trials;n++)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
      {
        birthdays[n][j]=rand()%365+1;
      }
    }
  for(int i=2;i<=50;i++)
     {
       numMatches=0;
       for(int n=0;n<trials;n++)
          {
         check=1;
         for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
              for(int k=j+1;k<=i;k++)
                {
                  if(birthdays[n][j]==birthdays[n][k]&&check)
                    {
                     numMatches++;
                     check=0;
                    }
                }
            }
      }
 cout << "Probability of " << i << " people in a room sharing a birthday is \t" <<
     (static_cast<float>(numMatches) / (trials)) << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is to check the probability of atleast two sharing a birthday among i number of people. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you need to use `goto` in such simple algorithm, you can tell you just didn't try hard enough.

Comment: what is the problem if I use goto?

Comment: Now I removed `goto` Is it fine now Saraph

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto) question, which also links to more duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what's going on here:

```
    for(int j = 1; j <= trials; j++) {
        for(k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            birthdays[k] = (rand() % 365) + 1;
        for(m = 1; m <= i; m++)
            birthdays[m] = (rand() % 365) + 1;
        if(birthdays[k] == birthdays[m])
            ++numMatches;
    }
```

You go through `i` birthdays and assign a random number, then you go through *the same `i` birthdays* and assign them a new random number. Then you try to find a match for just one value of `k` and `m` (which both happen to equal `i+1`, which isn't one of the values set!).

My suggestion is to break the problem down into smaller units that will make it easier to figure out how to code - here are the functions I would try to write.

```
/* randomizeBirthdays()
 *   Put n random birthdays into the pre-allocated array birthdays.
 *   birthdays must of course be of length <= n.
 */
void randomizeBirthdays(int * birthdays, int n);

/* hasMatchingBirthdays()
 *   Check if birthdays array has two people with the same birthday
 *   in the first n entries.
 *   Return value is boolean.
 */
bool hasMatchingBirthdays(int * const birthdays, int n);

/* probabilityOfMatch()
 *   Calculate the probability that at least 2 out of n people will
 *   have the same birthday, using nTrials number of trials.
 *   Return value is double.
 */
double probabilityOfMatch(int n, int nTrials);
```

If you break it down like this it becomes easier to write and easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments already:

> I think your aim is to test if 2 people in room of 2-50 people share
>   birthday, not if 2-50 people share birthday as you say in output. And
>   that's 2 people out of 23 have 50.7%, not 24.

I completely reworked your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

#define DAYS_IN_YEAR 365
#define TRIALS 10000

void clearArray (bool * array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < DAYS_IN_YEAR; i++)
        array[i] = false;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    bool birthdays[DAYS_IN_YEAR]; //we are trying to hit same day in year twice
    int r, numMatches;

    for(int i = 2; i < 50; i++)
    {
        numMatches = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < TRIALS; j++)
        {
            clearArray(birthdays);

            for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
            {
                r = rand() % DAYS_IN_YEAR; // == 0-364
                if (birthdays[r])
                {
                    numMatches++;
                    break;  // 2 people already have same birthdays here
                }
                birthdays[r] = true;
            }
        }

        cout << "Probability of 2 people having same birthday in room of " << i << " people is "
             << (float)numMatches / TRIALS << endl;

    }
 }
```

Output:

> Probability of 2 people having same birthday in room of 23 people is 0.516