# if condition override by switch and goto

Tags: c

In the below code the `if` condition is overridden by the `goto` statement and in the subsequent one, `if` condition in `switch` is overridden too. Please explain why `goto` and `switch` is doing this and is there a way to put condition on `goto` and inside `switch` as well.

```
int main()
{
    int x=3;
    goto LABEL;

    if(x < 0) {
        LABEL: printf("Label executed");
    }

    printf("\nEND MAIN");
    return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Label executed
END MAIN
```

---

```
int main()
{  
    int x = 2, y = -5;

    switch(x)
    {   if( y > 0)
        {   case 1:
                printf("case 1");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\n case 2");
                break;        
        } 
        case 3:
            printf("\n case 3");
            break;
        default :
            printf("\n Exit switch");  
     }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
case 2
```

Comment: Please read a [suggested C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn about basic concepts like goto

Comment: Maybe you want to leave the 1960ies/70ies and learn about structured programming. Spaghetti are fine on a plate with a good sauce, but not in programming. C provides loop statements to avoid writing such awful code.

Comment: Basically this is a misuse of goto. Whilst C has rules for resolving the issues, they don't matter to anyone except a compiler writer or an obfuscated C competition entrant. Don't jump into if blocks or put if blocks round switch cases.

Comment: It all boils down to: please don't grab a random piece of code from external sources and ask stackoverflow to explain it for you. Instead, learn from sources where the examples are delivered with an explanation so you can understand them for yourself. Once you learned the basics, you may ask specific quiestions here - but please one at a time and not multiple questions at once.

Comment: @Olaf:  Flippin' cheek!!  I didn't use `goto` in the 60s and 70s either.  That was for COBOL programmers.

Comment: I apologize if you consider this as simple question

Comment: @cdarke: Yes, and I had to use it in the 80ies, too in Apple BASIC and on the VIC64, but mostly in my assembly code (in the form of jump/branch instructions). But I think you got my point :-).

Comment: @Olaf - only kidding.

Comment: I haven't seen `goto` for ages

Answer (score 2):

[goto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto) jumps to this line:

```
LABEL: printf("Label executed");
```

ignoring the if statement and its condition, which explains the output.

---

`switch/case` is just a fancy `goto`, thus `switch(x)`, with `x = 2`, will go to case 2, ignoring the if statement, which explains the output.

---

PS: goto can lead to spaghetti code, thus is considered to be the black sheep of programming. It is suggested not to use it, unless you really really must to. Read more in [What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)

Comment: thanks gsamaras!So my point is that, is there any way to apply conditions on goto

Comment: @VishalRana - No.

Comment: @VishalRana Conditional branching is known as `if-else` statements in C, though C has no equivalent to assembler conditional branching. There is no reason to ever use `goto`. It has very few valid uses, and those few cases can be rewritten in better ways anyway.

Comment: @VishalRana glad the other users helped you, while I had lunch! =) Since you found the answer helpful, I would say that should accept it.

Comment: Sure @gsamaras.  Thanks a lot once again community. Actually this was my first question asked online. If anyone thinks that question was simple I apologize for that once again.