# Using goto statement

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double i, j;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter fnum");
    i = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    start:
    Console.WriteLine("Enter snum");
    j = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    if(j==0)
    {
        goto start;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Div result is {0}/{1}={2}", i, j, i / j);
}
```

I'm trying to implement Divide by zero using GOTO in c#. I got the result but here I would like to first calculate fnum/snum and print the result and then if I enter snum zero it should ask me enter snum other than zero.Then the goto start label should start working. But here in this case I was only able to execute fnum/snum by default.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter fnum");
i = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
start:
Console.WriteLine("Enter snum");
j = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Here if I enter snum zero it should take me to start label and ask me "enter second number other zero"

Can any one help me?

Comment: The `goto` statement is not recommended nowadays.

Comment: So you want a different message?  Then put it in the `if` before the `goto` and put the label after the original message.  Alternatively you can use a `do while` loop instead.

Comment: @S.Akbari Was it _ever_ recommended?

Comment: @UweKeim [Relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: Relevant [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful)

Comment: With doubles, `j==0` is already suspect. Will work here but it is as bad a habit as `goto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(j==0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("snum cannot be 0!!");
    goto start;
}
```

It is not recommended to use `goto` statements or get into the habit of using them.

They tend to increase complexity and create spaghetti code, they also affect readability as you add more and more of them. A bug caused by a goto statement can be tricky to fix. etc etc. others can edit more reasons not to use `goto` statements in if they wish.

Comment: What's the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely should **NOT** be using `goto`. Use a simple [`while` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while) instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double i, j = 0;
    Console.Write("Enter fnum: ");
    double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out i);

    Console.Write("Enter snum: ");
    while (j == 0)
    {
        double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out j);

        if(j==0)
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number that is not 0");
    }


    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Div result is {0}/{1}={2}", i, j, i / j);
}
```

Additionally, I have modified your code to use [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Convert.ToDouble()`, as is generally recommended. With it, you can implement a check to make sure that the user has actually entered a number. I have also changed `Console.WriteLine` to `Console.Write` for the inputs, which doesn't affect the flow of the program at all, but to me makes it better aesthetically.

Comment: This is not a "simple" `while` loop. A loop which by its constant condition pretends to be infinite, but actually has a `break;` in the middle, is a complex loop. A simple loop would suffice here by moving a bit of code into a function.

Comment: @hvd I was using the word "simple" to denote that the loop is easy to write and to understand. However, you're right that a simple loop would suffice, even without a function, as I have done in the edit.

Comment: You've forced yourself to duplicate the loop condition, which a separate function would've avoided, but given how trivial that loop condition is, I suppose that's not too bad.

Comment: can I apply try parse to CHAR ??

Comment: @sni Yes, you can.

Comment: @stybl can u give me an example ?

Comment: ages[i] = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ages);

What is wrong in the above statement ? @stybl

Comment: @sni `ages` is an array. Do `out ages[i]`. Extra piece of advice: don't use arrays. Use the built-in [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.