# Is there a way to handle multiple early return scenarios in Ruby with catch and throw?

Tags: ruby

I am currently using `begin/rescue/end` + exceptions to implement flow control. So, here is where I am capturing the exceptions and doing different things based on which exception is raised:

```
collection.each do |object|
  begin
    process_object(object)
  rescue SkippedRowError
    # handle skipped row
    next
  rescue AbortedRowError
    # handle aborted row
    next
  end
end
```

Because each object from the collection is being processed in a method (`process_object`, which calls a bunch of other methods and results in a deeply nested call stack), I can't use `next` to stop execution and proceed to the next object in the collection. Hence my use of exceptions.

However, I have read that exceptions should not be used for flow control and that, instead, I should use `catch/throw`. So, my question:

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing with `catch/throw`?

---

**My conclusion so far:** As far as I can tell, `catch/throw` is really only useful if you have a single scenario where you want to return early. If you have more than one scenario where you want to return early, then it looks like you have to nest `catch` blocks inside of each other. But in that case, you really only get access to a return value; there doesn't seem to be a good way to execute code.

Comment: I'm unclear what the motivation is. How would using `try`...`catch` potentially be cleaner code? There are other ways you *could* structure the code, which *might* be better (I'd need to know more context to advise), but I don't see what difference `try/catch` could make over `begin/end`.

Comment: might help if you showed a more complete example; this lacks context.

Comment: Currently, you are using exceptions to control flow, not “`begin`/`do`/`end`” (FYI: `begin`/`end` cannot control flow by any mean.) And using exceptions to control flow is considered to be a bad practice. Use normal standard iterator with early `next`/`break` instead.

Comment: @TomLord It is common advice that rescuing exceptions should not be used for control flow and that `catch/throw` should be used instead. I added more context to the question, which hopefully makes my use case more clear, but as far as I can tell, `catch/throw` won't work for what I'm trying to do. I'm just trying to verify that that is the case.

Comment: @mudasobwa Sorry, that should have been `begin/rescue/end`, not `begin/do/end`. I fixed that in an edit. I have read that using exceptions for control flow is considered bad practice, but I have a deeply nested call stack which eliminates `next/break` as control flow options. The other common suggestion is to use `catch/throw`, but that only seems to work well when you have a _single_ scenario in which you want to stop execution early. If you have more than one scenario where this is the case, you have to nest `catch` blocks, which seems like a mess.

Comment: @RichardJones It's also common advice that `throw/catch` should be avoided unless absolutely necessary - since it's basically the same as [writing a `GOTO` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)! I think your use of exceptions here is OK since it would qualify as "abandoning execution after something went wrong", but as I say there *are* other ways this could be written - but I really cannot give concrete advice without more context!

Comment: In particular, you may be better off skipping execution in a **guard clause** rather than via exceptions.

Comment: you could abstract your error handling into a new method and deal with it there as well. just pass the error and the object to the method handle what you want to and reraise the rest