# How do I keep program open in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm almost new to python and I'm making a kind of command line. I want to make it keep open after pressing enter. In C#, I used `goto` for example:

```
start:
a = Console.ReadLine("Enter Command:");
goto start;
```

But now, I don't know how to do that in python.

Comment: What should the program _do_ after the user input? Your C# program just asks the user for new input forever, which is not really all that useful.

Comment: Use a `while` loop?

Comment: There is not goto statement in Python, also even in languages where it is available using it is often considered bad practice c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `goto` in Python. However you can create an infinite loop.

```
while True:
   input()
```

Answer (score -1):

An example:

```
while True == True:
    dum = raw_input("Enter Command:")
```

Comment: `True == True` isn't particularly idiomatic and `raw_input` is Python 2.x only.

Comment: That said, raw_input() is much, much safer to use in Python2.