# break statement not working in else statement

Tags: c, loops, do-while, break, goto

I am getting this error in c. I was using the **"break"** statement in the else statement   and get this error message "error: break statement, not within loop or switch."

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int click;
    scanf("%d",&click);
    first_page:
        if(click == 1)
        {
            printf("OK");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid");
            goto first_page;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: The error actually tells you all you need to know ... that ain't how break works.

Comment: Why did you try to put the `break` statement not within loop or switch in the first place?nwyat did you expect it to do?

Comment: A `break` doesn't act on an `if`/`else`. Also, you'll never even reach that `break`, the `goto` will take you away first.

Comment: Also, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto) on why gotos are bad.

Comment: You're using `goto` to create an infinite loop. The standard way to create an infinite loop in C is with `while(1)` or `for(;;)`. Then you can end the loop with `break`. Of course, you need to move the `scanf` into the loop, or the loop will never break.

Comment: Isn't `first_page:` in the wrong place anyway? The code is quite bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The break statement may appear only in an iteration statement or a switch statement.

From the C Standard (6.8.6.3 The break statement)

> 1 A break statement shall appear only in or as a switch body or loop
>   body.

In your program it is redundant. The program has an infinite loop.

It seems what you mean is the following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int click;

    do
    {
        scanf("%d",&click);

        if(click == 1)
        {
            printf("OK");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid");
        }
    } while ( click != 1 );
}
```