# Why fscanf is giving segmentation fault while reading the data into a text file?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, text-files

I am trying to read data from a text file with some data in it.

---

My text file:

```
1 dior Asfiya 20 abcde 12345
2 abde Sabah 17 saar 5757657
```

---

My code:

```
typedef long long int ulong;
struct Customer
{
    char name[25];
    int acc_no;
    int age;
    char gender[2];
    char address[60];
    ulong phone;
    char password[10];


};
struct Customer add,check;

int new_acc()
{
        int c;
        FILE *p;
        FILE *q;
        p = fopen("test.txt","a");
        q = fopen("test.txt","r");
        if(p == NULL)
        {
            puts("Could't open file\n");
            return(-1);
        }
        if(q == NULL)
        {
            puts("Couldn't open file\n");
            return(-1);
        }
        account_no:
        printf("\nAdd record");
        printf("\nEnter account number: ");
        scanf("%d",&check.acc_no);
        while(c = fscanf(q,"%d %s %s %d %s %s %llu%[^\n]",&add.acc_no,add.password,add.name,&add.age,add.gender,add.address,&add.phone) == 7)
        {
            if(check.acc_no==add.acc_no)
            {
                printf("\nAccount no. already in use!");
                goto account_no;
            }
        }
        if(c != EOF){
            goto details;
        }
        details:
        add.acc_no = check.acc_no;
        printf("\nEnter password: ");
        scanf("%s",add.password);
        printf("\nFull Name: ");
        scanf("%s",add.name);
        printf("\nEnter your age: ");
        scanf("%d",&add.age);
        printf("\nEnter your gender: ");
        scanf(" %c",&add.gender);
        printf("\nEnter address: ");
        scanf("%s",add.address);
        printf("\nEnter phone number: ");
        scanf("%llu",&add.phone);
        fprintf(p,"%d %s %s %d %s %s %lld\n",add.acc_no,add.password,add.name,add.age,add.gender,add.address,add.phone);
        fclose(p);
        fclose(q);

}
```

While debugging the code it gives segmentation fault when the **while** loop starts. It worked perfectly fine before adding the first line of data into the file. I am not able to figure out why is this happening.

Comment: `char gender[2]` is quite short. If a word is bigger (like it seems to be the case here) it will crash your app. Always use a limited scan specifier in those cases.

Comment: The fragment `if(c != EOF){
            goto details;
        }
        details:` is weird; it will go to the label `details:` whether or not EOF is detected.

Comment: Your input data has 6 fields per line.  You are trying to read 7.  And apparently attempting to put the string "abcde" into add.gender which only has space for a string of length 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Remove `goto`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto).

Refactor this part of your code please.

---

About your arrays, which await to store a string - did you take in account the string NULL terminator, that also needs a cell of the array to be stored?

In any case, I see `gender` has a size of 2, but your input suggests that it needs more.

Your input has 7 tokens:

> 1 dior Asfiya 20 abcde 12345

that means that `gender` will **overflow, invoking Undefined Behavior (UB)**, since you will attempt to store a 4-character length string into an array of size 2. That might explain the crash.

You would have seen it by your check for 7 values, but there is also another problem in your code, as you can read in the next section.

You probably meant:

> 1 dior Asfiya 20 abcde f 12345

---

Change this:

```
while(c = fscanf(q,"%d %s %s %d %s %s %llu%[^\n]",&add.acc_no,add.password,add.name,&add.age,add.gender,add.address,&add.phone) == 7)
```

to this:

```
while((c = fscanf(q,"%d %s %s %d %s %s %llu%[^\n]",&add.acc_no,add.password,add.name,&add.age,add.gender,add.address,&add.phone)) == 7)
```

since, because of [operators priority](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the comparison happens *before* the assignment, which is not what you want. You want first to assign to your variable, and then compare, so use parentheses to specify the desired priority.

Comment: It helped. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting `c` correctly when you write:

```
while(c = fscanf(q,"%d %s %s %d %s %s %llu%[^\n]",&add.acc_no,add.password,add.name,&add.age,add.gender,add.address,&add.phone) == 7)
```

This is setting `c` to the result of the `==` comparison, because `==` has higher precedence than `=`.

Also, you don't need `[^\n]` at the end of the format string. `%d` at the beginning will skip over any whitespace, including the newline at the end of the previous line.

It should be:

```
while((c = fscanf(q,"%d %s %s %d %s %s %llu",&add.acc_no,add.password,add.name,&add.age,add.gender,add.address,&add.phone)) == 7)
```

I'm not sure what you intend with

```
        if(c != EOF){
            goto details;
        }
        details:
```

Since `details:` is immediately after the `if` statement, you go there whether or not the condition succeeds.

You should get out of the habit of using `goto`, it's generally considered poor programming style. Put the code that should run when the condition is true inside the `if`. You can use `continue` and `break` to restart and end a loop.