# How to print array which I use in a map?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, stdmap

Here is my code:

```
typedef array<int,6> Array;
Array dayHours{0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

I am using this data in here:

```
void Schedule::studentSchedule()
{
    string c, s;
    int courseNum;
    list<string>::iterator studentLoc;
    map<pair<string, int>, pair<string, Array> >::iterator location;

    cout << "Enter the student name" << endl;
    cin >> s;
    cout << "Enter how many course you want?" << endl;
    cin >> courseNum;
wrongCourse:
    cout << "Enter the course names you want" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < courseNum; ++i)
    {
        cin >> c;
        auto predicate = [&](auto& course) { return compareName(course, c); };
        studentLoc = find(getStudentList().begin(), getStudentList().end(), s);
        location = find_if(getMatchMap().begin(), getMatchMap().end(), predicate);
        map<pair<string, int>, pair<string, Array> >::iterator it;
        cout << "Student:\t\t" << "Course:\t\t" << "Course Day:\t\t" << "Course Hours:" << endl;
        if (studentLoc != getStudentList().end() && location != getMatchMap().end())
        {
            getCourseScList().insert({ make_pair(s,c),make_pair(getDay1()[i],getDayHours()) });
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The course you're writing isn't available.Please enter existed courses!" << endl;
            goto wrongCourse;
        }
    }
}
```

I am sending the array to the map here:

```
if (studentLoc != getStudentList().end() && location != getMatchMap().end())
{
    getCourseScList().insert({ make_pair(s,c),make_pair(getDay1()[i],getDayHours())});
}
```

The question is how can I reach the array element:

```
map< pair<string, string>, pair<string, Array> >::iterator last;
for (last = getCourseScList().begin(); last != getCourseScList().end(); ++last)
{
    cout << (last->first).first << "\t\t\t\t"
         << (last->first).second
         << "\t\t" << (last->second).first
         << (last->second).second << endl;
}
```

The `(last->second).second` is representing my array but I can not print this to screen. What can I do?

Comment: *"How to print array which I use in a map?"* The same way that one which is not in `map`. I meant, you might reduce your sample to `array<int,6> Array;
Array dayHours{0,0,0,0,0,0}; std::cout << dayHours; // Error: How to print dayHours?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `operator<<` defined for [`std::array<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), Therefore, you need to iterate through the elements in the array to print it.

Let say your map is

```
using Array = std::array<int, 6> ;
using MyMap = std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::pair<std::string, Array>>;
```

Then using iterators [`MyMap::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin). (Assuming you have `MyMap& getCourseScList();` getter overload in your class. In case of `MyMap::const_iterator`, you should be having `const MyMap& getCourseScList() const;` overload)

```
#include <array>
#include <map>

for (MyMap::iterator last = getCourseScList().begin(); // preferably cbegin() and cend(), as the entries will not be modified
                     last != getCourseScList().end(); ++last)
{ 
    // print the key-pair (i.e. std::pair<std::string, std::string>)
    std::cout << last->first.first << "\t\t\t\t" << last->first.second << "\t\t";
    // print the first of value-pair (i.e. string of std::pair<std::string, Array>)
    std::cout << last->second.first;
    // now to print the array `Array`
    for (const int element : last->second.second)
        std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

---

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you could use *[range-based `for`-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)*, instead of the iterator based one.

```
for (const auto& entry : getCourseScList())
{
    std::cout << entry.first.first << " " << entry.first.second << "\n";
    std::cout << entry.second.first << " ";
    for (const int element : entry.second.second)
       std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

---

However, if you have access to the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) or later compiler use *[structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)* for *key-value* pair, along with a *[range-based `for`-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)* to make it more intuitive.

```
for (auto const&[key, value]: getCourseScList())
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^             -->structured binding
{
    std::cout << key.first << " " << key.second << "\n";
    std::cout << value.first << " ";
    for (const int element : value.second)  
       std::cout << element << " ";
}
```

---

As a side note, please keep in mind the followings:

- [What is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)
- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @sonelektrikci Your welcome. Check out the update for the alternative in C++17.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create your own stream insertion operator (`<<`) for your type `Array`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::array<int, 6> Array;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Array& arr)
{
    std::copy(arr.cbegin(), arr.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(o, " "));
    return o;
}
```

Then you should be able to do the following without the loop:

```
std::cout << last->second.second;
```

which will call the operator above automatically.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    Array dayHours{ 0,1,0,0,0,0 };
    std::cout << dayHours;
    //prints 0 1 0 0 0 0
}
```

Comment: I tried overloaded operator but I can't use it in my class.

Comment: @sonelektrikci You should define the operator `<<` outside your class.