# What's the problem in the outer while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int x,y,n=0,ch='y';
  while(ch=='y')//problem loop
  {
    gno:
    x=rand()%9999+1000;
    y=x;
    n=0;
    while(y>0)
    {
      y=y/10;
      n++;
      if(n>3&&n<3)
        goto gno;
    }
    cout<<x<<endl;
    cin>>ch;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run the above code, it displays one random number as it should. But after that even when I enter the value of ch as "y" (without the quotes, of course!) the while loop marked as "problem loop" just doesn't continue. Ya, I get it that it's some kind of a runtime error but can anyone please specify what is causing this problem, and by making what exact changes to the code will let me run it successfully?

Comment: Which is it: C++ or C?

Comment: Because `ch` is an `int`. Change it to `char`.

Comment: When is `n<3&&n>3` ever true?

Answer (score 3):

You defined `ch` as an `int`, which means that `cin` will interpret the input as an integer and read it into `ch`. You can observe that this happens when you enter `121` and the code continues. To fix your issue, just change

```cpp
int x,y,n=0,ch='y';
```

into

```cpp
int x,y,n=0;
char ch='y';
```

Also, you have an if statement that will never happen, so you might as well get rid of the `if(n>3&&n<3)` and the `goto`. Keep in mind that [goto is bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)