# Subroutine in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can anyone share me a light on how to create a subroutine in a stored procedure in SQL Server?

I have a procedures in Oracle that will call a subroutine within the same procedures for 50 times in different lines in the procedure. Now I want to recreate the same procedure in SQL Server. Could you share me some light on how to do this?

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a subroutine in SQL Server. But a stored procedure can call another stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your subroutine is performing data modifications (CRUD) or need to use temporary tables(#teporary_table) it needs to be [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15). In other cases, you can use create a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You can choose from different types of functions depending on their complexity and return values:

- scalar function - returns one value
- inline table-valued - it's like view with parameters (you cannot declare table variables for example, its one `SELECT` statement) and returns rowset
- multi-statement table-valued - returns rowset but you can have more complex logic

Also, in SQL Server there is [SQL CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration) and you can create functions or procedures (or as called them "subroutines") in `.net` code.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you have stored procedures and table and scalar functions. Another feature that is convenient are common table expressions.

**Functions** you can use directly in SQL statements (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `JOIN`), so they seamless to reuse.

Table function:

```
SELECT *
FROM myFunction(@UserID) as f
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON f.UserID = u.ID
```

Scalar function you can put in `SELECT` part of query.

```
SELECT u.ID, myFunction(u.ID)
FROM users as u
```

**Common table expressions** are nice for readability:

```
;WITH MyCTP AS
(
    // complex SQL
)
SELECT *
FROM myTable INNER JOIN MyCTP ON...
```

You can have multiple CTEs before SELECT statement, but you can only use them in the statment above which they were declared.

**Stored procedures**

They are a bit of pain in the a$$, because you need to capture result into variables in order to use them in the calling stored procedure.

```
 DECLARE @Input INT
 DECLARE @Result INT

 EXEC myStoredProcedure @Input, @Result OUT
```

If procedure outputs table, it gets even more complicated. You need to use cursor to capture result.

Answer (score -1):

A trick:

```
create proc MyProc @MySub varchar(20) = ''
as
if @MySub = 'MySub' goto MySub

print 'MyProc'
exec MyProc MySub
return

MySub:
print 'MySub'
return
```

Comment: [What is the problem with GOTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto). Not only is this bad code in any language and doesn't really answer the question, there are *good* answers already