# The GOTO command doesn't work when I use it in a while loop

Tags: python, goto

I am try to make a choose system. I want to use the GOTO command. But it actually doesn't works. I've already installed the goto-statement in pip.

```
from goto import with_goto
print('Welcome to * sell system.')
print('Choose the action:\n(1) Buy *\n(2) Contact us\n(3) Exit')
# Choose the action
while action := input('> '):
    if action in '1':
        break
    if action in '2':
        print('Contact Us\n* is a brand of *')
        break
    if action in '3':
        exit()
    print('Only 1 and 2 allowed.') 
# Choose the categories
if action in '1':
    print('Choose categories of merchandises.\n(1) *\n(2) *')
    print('Enter 0 to exit') 
# Choose the merchandise (A while in a if)   
    while category := input('> '):
        if category in '1':
            label .choose_merchandises
            print('Choose the merchandises.\n(1) *- *')
            while merchandises := input('> '):
                if merchandises in '1':
                    print('Title:*- *\nPrice: *\nAmount: *\nDetails:\nDo you wanna buy it?\n(y/n)')
                    while wannabuy := input('> '):
                        if wannabuy == "y":
                            print('Redirecting to pay...')
                            break
                        if wannabuy == "n":
                            goto .choose_merchandises                    
                        print('Only y or n allowed.')
                    print ('1')
        if category in '2':
            print('2')
            break
    print('Only 1 and 2 allowed.')
```

And it told me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\*\*.py", line 18, in <module>
    label .choose_merchandises
NameError: name 'label' is not defined
```

How can I do. Appreciate.

Patch:
I am a beginner of python. It is a choosing system in that people can do what they want to do, like contact us, buy some stuff, etc. At first, users choose the action like Buy some stuff, contact us. Users choose the categories of merchandises and then choose the merchandises.

Comment: Consider not using `goto` at all. [There's a good reason its not part of high-level languages like Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto). Your code is highly nested and difficult to read/understand/debug -- spaghetti code as described in the linked post. Stick to using conditionals, loops and functions instead (structured code).

Comment: I'm actually is a beginner of python. I don't know how to use these commands at all. But I'm still learning. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A finite state machine could be a suitable design pattern for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @reachead As a beginner, you should not use `goto` at all. In fact, many universities ban the use of `goto` for beginners (and rightly so, to prevent misuse)

Comment: There are good reasons why Python does not have a `goto` statement. Then someone implemented it as an on [April fool joke](http://entrian.com/goto/). Don't be an April fool! ;-)

Comment: Thank you. But, I mean... If I don't use goto. What command should I use?

Comment: As mentioned, you can use loops, functions and conditionals -- structured code.