# Guess the number problem. When anything other than integers is entered program shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int num, count = 0, ans;
    srand(time(0));
    ans = rand() % 1000;

    printf("Im thinking about a three digit number.\nCan you guess it??\n");

    do {
        printf("\nENTER YOUR GUESS:\n");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if (num < ans) {
            printf("Enter a higher number!!!\n");
        } else if (num > ans) {
            printf("Enter a lower number!!!\n");
        } else if (num == ans) {
            printf("\n\t   =================\n");
            printf("\t|| CONGRATULATIONS!! ||\n\t   =================\n\nYOU HAVE GUESSED THE CORRECT NUMBER.\n");
        } else {
            printf("ENTER A VALID 3 DIGIT NUMBER!!!");
        }
        count++;
    } while(num != ans);

    printf("You took %d chances to answer!\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

When the user enters characters other than digit such as letters or symbols it goes into printing `Enter a lower number!!!` indefinitely. Please can anyone tell how to avoid it. Also the last `else` statement is supposedly redundant and cannot be reached. Is there anyway to make this?

Comment: `scanf()` is not meant to deal with user input: it is meant to deal with formatted input (hence the `f`). Use `fgets()` for user input.

Comment: Additionally, since you do not check for error conditions, the input remains unconsumed, and you're left reading the same problematic input over and over

Comment: @776 Shivamrut, What is the return value from the function `scanf("%d", &num);` when a non-numeric text is entered?  Why is code not testing the return value?  What do you want to do with that non-numeric text?  There is no code posted to consume it.

Comment: If the user is expected (feared) to enter non-numbr input, then do not promise the program that there will be clean number input. With `ResultToBeChecked=scanf("%d", &num);` you do promise that and with the blank `scanf("%d", &num);` you even ignore that it might fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should detect invalid input by testing the return value of `scanf()`. Offending input can then be discarded using a simple loop. Note however that validating input with `scanf()` alone is very tricky and produces misleading behavior. It is recommended to read a line of input with `fgets()` and parse it with `sscanf()` or `strtol` which has better defined semantics.

Regarding the redundant `else`, the redundancy is in the test `if (num == ans)`: remove this test and the final `else` clause.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    char buf[32];
    int num, count = 0, ans;
    char ch;

    srand(time(0));
    ans = rand() % 1000;

    printf("I am thinking about a three digit number.\n"
           "Can you guess it?\n");

    for (;;) {
        printf("\nENTER YOUR GUESS:\n");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
            printf("premature end of file\n");
            break;
        }
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d%c", &num, &ch) != 2 || ch != '\n') {
            printf("invalid input: %s\n", buf);
            continue;
        }
        if (num == ans) {
            printf("\n\t   =================\n");
            printf("\t|| CONGRATULATIONS!! ||\n"
                   "\t   =================\n\n"
                   "YOU HAVE GUESSED THE CORRECT NUMBER.\n");
            break;
        }
        if (num < ans) {
            printf("Enter a higher number!!!\n");
        } else {
            printf("Enter a lower number!!!\n");
        }
        count++;
    }
    printf("You took %d chances to answer!\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What I don't like about `sscanf` is that, according to [7.21.6.2 ¶10 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10), the behavior is undefined if the result of the conversion is not representable in the object, i.e. if you used the `%d` conversion specifier and the converted value is not in the range representable as an `int`. The function `strtol` does not have this problem, as the behavior is always well-defined. However, since this is only a corner case, I am still upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an infinite loop because when the user does not enter a number, `scanf` will fail without consuming any input. Therefore, the next time you call `scanf`, it will read the exact same input again and fail again for exactly the same reason.

Therefore, after using `scanf` with line-based user input, unless you want to do something with the rest of the line, you should always discard the remainder of the line, by consuming all characters on the input stream up to an including the newline character. You can do this for example by defining and calling the following function:

```
void discard_remainder_of_line( void )
{
    int c;

    do
    {
        c = getchar();

    } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );
}
```

A shorter way of accomplishing the same thing would be to write:

```
for ( int c; (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF; )
    ;
```

Also, before using the result of a `scanf` operation, you should always check the return value of `scanf`, in order to verify that it was successful.

However, I don't recommend that you use `scanf` for line-based user input, because when dealing with such input, `scanf` does not behave in an intuitive manner. For example, as pointed out above, it does not always read one line at once.

Therefore, I recommend that you use the function [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead, which always reads one line at once, provided that the memory buffer is large enough to store the entire line. After reading in a whole line as a string using `fgets`, you can convert the string to a number, by using the function [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

It would probably be best to create a function `get_int_from_user` which prompts the user to input a number, and if the input is not valid, prints an error message and reprompts the user for input. As soon as the input is valid, it returns the input as an `int`. In the program below, I call this function `get_int_from_user`.

That way, all you have to do to make your code work is to write this function `get_int_from_user` and to change the lines

```
printf("\nENTER YOUR GUESS:\n");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

to:

```
num = get_int_from_user( "Enter your guess: " );
```

Also, in your code, the line `else {printf("ENTER A VALID 3 DIGIT NUMBER!!!");}` is redundant, because that code is unreachable. That code will only be reached when `num < ans` is false and `num > ans` is false and `num == ans` is false. However, it is not possible for all three conditions to be false.

Performing the check `num == ans` is also redundant, because if `num < ans` is false and `num > ans` is false, then `num == ans` must be true.

After making the changes described above, your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt );

int main( void )
{
    int num, count = 0, ans;
    srand(time(0));
    ans = rand()%1000;

    printf("Im thinking about a three digit number.\nCan you guess it??\n");

    do
    {
        num = get_int_from_user( "Enter your guess: " );

        if(num < ans)
        {
            printf("Enter a higher number!!!\n");
        }
        else if(num > ans)
        {
            printf("Enter a lower number!!!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\t   =================\n");
            printf("\t|| CONGRATULATIONS!! ||\n\t   =================\n\nYOU HAVE GUESSED THE CORRECT NUMBER.\n");
        }

        count++;

    } while(num != ans);

    printf( "You took %d attempts to answer!\n", count );

    return 0;
}

int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt )
{
    //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[1024], *p;
        long l;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        l = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "Error converting string to number!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "Number out of range error!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6abc" gets rejected
        for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            {
                printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return l;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Im thinking about a three digit number.
Can you guess it??
Enter your guess: test
Error converting string to number!
Enter your guess: 6abc
Unexpected input encountered!
Enter your guess: 10000000000
Number out of range error!
Enter your guess: 500
Enter a higher number!!!
Enter your guess: 750
Enter a lower number!!!
Enter your guess: 625
Enter a lower number!!!
Enter your guess: 562
Enter a higher number!!!
Enter your guess: 593
Enter a higher number!!!
Enter your guess: 609
Enter a lower number!!!
Enter your guess: 601
Enter a higher number!!!
Enter your guess: 605
Enter a lower number!!!
Enter your guess: 603
Enter a lower number!!!
Enter your guess: 602

           =================
        || CONGRATULATIONS!! ||
           =================

YOU HAVE GUESSED THE CORRECT NUMBER.
You took 10 attempts to answer!
```

Further reading about why not to use `scanf`:

[A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: I'm afraid `goto continue_outer_loop` is not OK, especially as there are simple alternatives, eg: `if (!p[strcspn(p, " \t\r\n")]) return l;`

Comment: @chqrlie: In order to determine the category if a character, in my opinion, it is generally not a good idea to compare with hard-coded characters. It is usually better to use the functions in `ctype.h`. The advantage of using these functions is that the behavior of these functions depends on the current [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale). For example, in the default `"C"` locale, [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) only returns true for `a`-`z` and `A` to `Z`, but not for example for `ê`. [continued in next comment]

Comment: @chqrlie: [continued from previous comment] However, by changing the locale, the behavior of `isalpha` can be changed to also consider the character `ê` to be an alphabetical character. For the same reason, I believe it is generally better to use [`isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) instead of hard-coding all whitespace characters.

Comment: @chqrlie: Using `goto` to break out of a nested loop [is generally considered appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto/3517746#3517746).