# How to break out of a nested loop?

Tags: c++, break

Is there any way to break this without if/else conditionals for each layer?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        while (true) 
        { 
            while (true) 
            { 
                break; break; break; 
            } 
        }
    }
    
    cout << "END";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 breaks inside the same loop? You just need 1 for each loop.

Comment: You could use `goto`, but you are probably better off rethinking your design.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself in such a situation, the real question to ask is: why is my logic is so convoluted that something like that is needed. This is an indication that things should be broken up and refactored, to simplify the logic to the point that this is no longer needed.

Comment: Though the above is just an example, I don't agree. I'm pretty comfortable with flow control, and things often require 3 layers, especially in gamedev... Heck, a simple 2D scan requires two...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the logic in a function or lambda.

Instead of `break; break; break;` (which won't work) you can `return;`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    auto nested_loops = []
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            while (true) 
            { 
                while (true) 
                { 
                    // Done with all the looping
                    return;
                } 
            }
        }
    };

    nested_loops();
    cout << "END";
    return 0;
}
```

Or (same effect, different style)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    [] {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            while (true) 
            { 
                while (true) 
                { 
                    // Done with all the looping
                    return;
                } 
            }
        }
    } ();

    cout << "END";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do `[]{ ... }();` then you do not need to give it a name

Comment: @Slava yep!  I debated that style.  Or `std::invoke( []{...} );` if you prefer to know _immediately_ that the lambda will be invoked immediately,  Styles vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `break` individual **loop**, then you can use `break` in their respect **loop**.

Putting too many or single `break` within a **loop**, will only `break` that **loop** that it is within it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    [] {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            while (true) 
            { 
                while (true) 
                { 
                    break;
                } 
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    } ();

    cout << "END";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to break out of a nested loop, you can use the [`goto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) statement.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        while (true) 
        { 
            while (true) 
            { 
                goto break_outer_loop;
            } 
        }
    }

break_outer_loop:
    
    cout << "END";

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `goto` should generally be avoided. However, for breaking out of a nested loop, [it is generally considered acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3517746/12149471).