# Change the flow of code dynamically in Python

Tags: python, goto

So im writing this calculator program, and at the end of it I want to give the user an option to run it again or close the program.

I thought there was a "goto" function, but apparenty that doesnt exist.

what I tried:

```
if operator == "+":
    answer = number1 + number2
    print("") #line break
    print(f"the answer is {answer}")
    
redoq=input(print("would you like to redo? (y/n):"))
if redoq == "y" or "Y":
    goto(start)

if redoq == "n" or "n":
    print("Okay! This window will now close.")
    time.sleep(5)
```

what happened:

```
> "goto" is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Where exactly is the goto function defined?

Answer (score 0):

`GOTO` is not considered good practice these days - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3517726/7128934). Python does not have an inbuilt goto. For your purpose, you could have another helper function that calls the main function recursively until you want to exit. See example below:

```py
def foo():
    print("foo ran")
    
def call_foo():
    foo()
    
    check = input("Repeat?")
    if check == "y":
        call_foo()
    else:
        print("exiting...")
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and make the file run itself, this should make it work.

```py
exec(open('calculatorprogram.py').read())
```

You could also make it a function:

```py
def calculatorprog():
##main program goes here
    repeat = input("Redo? y/n ")
    if repeat in "y", "Y":
        calculatorprog()
    else:
        break
```