# How to get user input in a C# console application and process it as items of an order?

Tags: c#, console-application

I searched a lot in the internet but didn't find anything helpful
I'm trying to get a number from the user and then use it to:

1. Write the name of that product.
2. At the end to show everything they want to order
3. Calculate the price of the order.

So if they say 1, 2, 5 it prints "CPU, GPU, 100000". I just want to know how to add the second part to get input from user and then list all of them at the end.

```
string[] computer = { "Cpu", "Gpu", "Ram", "Hard", "Motherboard" };
int[] price = { 30000, 70000, 20000, 25000, 40000 };
Console.WriteLine("0 = Cpu , 1=Gpu , 2=Ram 3,=Hard 4=Motherboard", "each Time Put Number For Your Order , Put 5 To Calculate");

Start:

Console.Write("Enter What You Want To Order : ");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
List<string> list = new List<string>();
**list.Add(computer[num]);** (This is the part that shows the error
if (num < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(computer[num]);
    goto Start;
}
else if (num == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Finished Proccess");
    goto Next;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Valid");
}

Next:

foreach (var lol in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(lol);
}
```

I tried using list.add but it didn't work  -  `list.Add(computer[num]);`

Comment: Move following to beginning of the code.  You deleting the old list every time you add one item : List<string> list = new List<string>();

Comment: "This is the part that shows the error" - what error? :)

Comment: Do not use jump statements `goto`, they are terrible for code quality and readability. You can achieve what you want to do using a while loop

Comment: Point in case, because you are using the jump statement, your list is getting continually garbage collected and then reinitialized but you can't even really tell because instead of a clearly scoped loop of any form (for, while, lambda in LINQ, etc), all you see is a jump statement

Comment: This smells like HOMEWORK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code to make it work as per your requirements.

First, as pointed out by @jdweng in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77579515/i-want-to-add-inbox-of-an-array-to-a-list-using-readline/77579578#comment136767790_77579515), you need to move the assignation of your List *before* `Start:`, because using `Goto:` you are coming back to that point and resetting the list to new() each iteration. Also note that you only need to store `integers` in the list to keep track of all the items you buy, so you can use a `List<int>` instead of a `List<string>`. I've called it `order`:

```
List<int> order = new List<int>();

Start:
```

For the options `if (num == 5)` and `else` you are not buying anything so you need to `.Add` a new item to the orders *only* inside the `if (num < 5)` block, which is the case when you buy an item:

```
if (num < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(computer[num]);
    order.Add(num);

    goto Start;
}
```

Finally, in order to show the list of all your items in the order, since the two arrays `computer` and `price` loop through the list `orders` and for each order, print both the item name and the price. In each iteration, you also add the price to the variable `totalPrice` to keep track of the total cost of your order and print it in the end:

```
Next:

Console.WriteLine("You ordered:");

int totalPrice = 0;

foreach(var item in order)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\t{computer[item]} {price[item]}");

    totalPrice += price[item];
}

Console.WriteLine($"Total: {totalPrice}");
```

All in all, the complete program looks like this:

```
string[] computer = { "Cpu", "Gpu", "Ram", "Hard", "Motherboard" };
int[] price = { 30000, 70000, 20000, 25000, 40000 };
Console.WriteLine("0 = Cpu , 1=Gpu , 2=Ram 3,=Hard 4=Motherboard", "each Time Put Number For Your Order , Put 5 To Calculate");

List<int> order = new List<int>();

Start:

Console.Write("Enter What You Want To Order : ");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (num < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(computer[num]);
    order.Add(num);

    goto Start;
}
else if (num == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Finished Proccess");
    goto Next;
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Valid");
}

Next:

Console.WriteLine("You ordered:");

int totalPrice = 0;

foreach(var item in order)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\t{computer[item]} {price[item]}");

    totalPrice += price[item];
}

Console.WriteLine($"Total: {totalPrice}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I agree with @Narish that you should probably refrain from using `Goto:`, `Start:` and `Next:`, as it makes the code harder to read, and it makes your code brittle, unnecessarily convoluted and prone to bugs and brittle (see [what is wrong with using goto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517726/what-is-wrong-with-using-goto)). Instead, you can control the execution flow of your program with `while`, `for` or `foreach` loops.

Also, take into account that the index in C# arrays and collections are [0-based](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/array-indexing-0-based-or-1-based-dd89d631d11c), which means that the first position is 0, the second position is 1, and so on. Therefore, in your example:

> So if they say 1, 2, 5 it prints "CPU, GPU

1 and 2 correspond to Gpu and Ram, not to Cpu and Gpu.

Answer (score 1):

So many poor practices here :(

```
// Pull out some of the code into separate methods
void PrintMenu(IEnumerable<(string Name, decimal Price)> items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter what you want to order:\n");

    int idx = 0;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{idx++} = {item.name}";
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Enter the number for each item you want to order.\nEnter {idx} to calculate the total.");
}

void PrintCart(IEnumerable<(string Name, decimal Price)> items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You ordered:");
    decimal total = 0.0M;

    int idx = 1;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{idx++}.  {item.Name} ({item.Price})");
        total+= item.Price;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"TOTAL: ${total}");
}


// You could use a dictionary or class for this as well, 
// but paired arrays/collections that match by index are NOT GOOD.
// Also, decimal rather than int for anything to do with money
var items = new List<(string Name, decimal Price)> {
  ("Cpu", 30000.0M), ("Gpu", 70000.0M), ("Ram", 20000.0M), ("Hard", 25000.0M), ("Motherboard",40000.0M)
};

// Loops instead of Goto!
bool okay = true;
while(okay)
{   
    var cart = new List<(string item, decimal price)>();
    int num = -1;

    // use the length of the items list instead of a hard-coded value
    while (num != items.Length)
    {
        PrintMenu();
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
        if (num >= 0 && num < items.Length)
        {
            cart.Add(items[num]);
            Console.WriteLine($"{items[num].Name} added");
        }
        else if (num < 0 || num > items.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not valid");
        }
    }
    if (cart.Length > 0)
    {
        PrintCart(cart);
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("Nothing ordered!");

    Console.WriteLine("Make another order (Y/N)? ");
    char input = (Console.ReadLine().TrimStart() + "N").ToUpper()[0];
    okay = (input == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: I commend you for adding an improved solution, but it would be even better to explain a little bit why your alternative is better than OP's. E.g. "So many poor practices" <-- "Which?", "Why is a dictionary or a List<(string item, decimal price)> is preferable to an array?", "Why use loops instead of Goto?", etc.

Comment: @jarmanso7 in the comments in the code.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways; you can try get the list *in one go*, e.g. user provides `"1, 3, 2"` and you have a list of `1, 2, 3`.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// [...]

Console.Write("Enter a List of What You Want to Order : ");

List<int> choice = Regex
  .Matches("[0-4]")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
  .Distinct() // Let's get rid of duplicates
  .OrderBy(item => item) 
  .ToList();
```

or you can ask question after question:

```
List<int> choice = new List<int>();

// We keep asking user until "5" is put
while (true) {
  Console.WriteLine("Enter What You Want to Order 0..4 or 5 to Exit: ");

  if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int item))
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer, please, try again");
  else if (item < 0 || item > 5)
    Console.WriteLine("Item should be in 0..5 range");
  else if (item == 5)
    break;
  else if (!choice.Contains(item)) // Let's get rid of duplicates
    choice.Add(item);
}

choice.Sort();
```